# Dirty unmount of nginx cache dir on reboot

Tags: ubuntu, mount, nginx, reboot

I have a file based mount, used for nginx cache dir, so that the hundreds of thousands of little files don't clutter the main file system.

It's fstab line is the following:

```
/data/project/cache.img /data/project/cache ext4 discard,defaults,nofail 0 2
```

My problem that it cannot be unmounted cleanly at system restart. If I manually stop the nginx service and manually unmount it, then there are no problems, but automatically it generates the following journalctl logs:

```
May 17 01:09:44 hn systemd-fstab-generator[334]: Checking was requested for "/data/project/cache.img", but it is not a device.
May 17 01:09:44 hn systemd[1]: Mounting /data/project/cache...
May 17 01:09:44 hn systemd[1]: Mounted /data/project/cache.
--- reboot issued ---
May 17 01:21:25 hn systemd-fstab-generator[14467]: Checking was requested for "/data/project/cache.img", but it is not a device.
May 17 01:21:30 hn systemd-fstab-generator[14758]: Checking was requested for "/data/project/cache.img", but it is not a device.
May 17 01:21:31 hn systemd-fstab-generator[14783]: Checking was requested for "/data/project/cache.img", but it is not a device.
May 17 01:21:33 hn systemd-fstab-generator[15701]: Checking was requested for "/data/project/cache.img", but it is not a device.
May 17 01:21:33 hn systemd-fstab-generator[15724]: Checking was requested for "/data/project/cache.img", but it is not a device.
May 17 01:22:46 hn systemd[1]: Unmounting /data/project/cache...
May 17 01:22:46 hn umount[18509]: umount: /data/project/cache: target is busy.
May 17 01:22:46 hn systemd[1]: data-project-cache.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited status=32
May 17 01:22:46 hn systemd[1]: Failed unmounting /data/project/cache.
```

Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

Looks related to that `2` at the end of the corresponding `/etc/fstab` entry. Changing this `2` into a `0` would probably fix the issue, at the cost no not `fsck`ing your filesystem anymore.

See [`man fstab`](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html)